# When will a Clang AST node have multiple parents?

Tags: clang, libtooling

The class clang::ASTContext has a method:

```
DynTypedNodeList getParents(const NodeT &Node)
```

which returns a list of parent nodes of a given AST node.

Commonly AST as a tree will be a tree structure, but for some reasons (perhaps performance reasons) Clang allows a node have multiple parents.

Under what conditions (what C++ source code pattern), getParents() will return more than one parents?

Comment: The existing answer only provide 1 example, more answers about more examples are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original answer (incorrect)

AST is a tree, and each node has exactly one parent. `getParents`, though, returns not only a parent, but a parent of a parent and so on. So, in fact, the function should be better named something like `getAncestors`.

### Updated answer

The original answer is indeed incorrect and `getParents` returns exactly one node for the vast majority of AST nodes. Here is a comment from `clang-tidy` that covers the topic:

> The case that a Stmt has multiple parents is rare but does actually occur in the parts of the AST that we're interested in. Specifically, InitListExpr nodes cause ASTContext::getParent() to return multiple parents for certain nodes in their subtree because RecursiveASTVisitor visits both the syntactic and semantic forms of InitListExpr, and the parent-child relationships are different between the two forms.

Maybe there are other nodes as well, but I couldn't find information on that.

Comment: Thats good, now you get 27 bucks and I get my 1 downvote buck back plus 2 selection bucks and now I returned to a never downvoted states again.